# Print Mysql data in HTML using Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm learning Node.js now, but I'm a little bit confused.

I'm receiving data using the following code:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');  
var connection = mysql.createConnection({  
  host     : 'localhost',  
  user     : 'root',  
  password : '',  
  database : 'db'  
});  

connection.connect();  

connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, rows, fields)   
{  
  if (err) throw err;  

  console.log(rows[0]);  

});  

connection.end();
```

My debug console is showing the first row from my database table, but I would like to print this value in my HTML page. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to look into [creating an http server](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) to send those results to an html site.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'))

var mysql      = require('mysql');  
var connection = mysql.createConnection({  
  host     : 'localhost',  
  user     : 'root',  
  password : '',  
  database : 'db'  
});        

app.get('/rows', function (req, res) {
  connection.connect();  

  connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, rows, fields)   
  {  
      connection.end();

      if (err) throw err;  

      res.json(rows); 

  });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Running this file will create a server on port 3000 on your machine.

In your project, create a directory called `public` at the root level. In there you can make a file called `index.html` with something like the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My db rows</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="table"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
             var opts = {
                 url: 'http://localhost:3000/rows/'
             };

             fetch(opts)
                 .then((res) => {
                     if (res.ok) {
                         return res.json();
                     }
                  })
                  .then((rows) => {
                      for (let row of rows) {
                          // row will be a mysql row -- you can loop over these and do what you want with them
                      }
                   })
                   .catch(console.log);
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Note: I am using the new fetch API to execute my request, but you could use jquery or XHR just as easily. The fetch api can be explained in more detail [here](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch).

And then navigate to `http://localhost:3000/index.html` in your browser to see the results.